# Как сократить массив?

Tags: массивы, php

Здравствуйте господа Хешкодевцы, вообшем есть такой массив:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => name
                    [title] => title

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => name
                    [title] => title

                )

        )
    и т.д.

)
```

можно ли добиться такого результата? т.е. убрать `[0]`(Че порылся в гугле ответов не нашел):

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (

            [id] => 1
            [name] => name
            [title] => title

        )

    [2] => Array
        (

            [id] => 4
            [name] => name
            [title] => title

        )
    и т.д.

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($mass as $k=>$v)$mass[$k]=$v[0];
```

> Че порылся в гугле

Подвел тебя Эрнесто.

Comment: Супер! Спасибо)